# Passing arguments in dataclass representation

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have a below `NormalClass` that I want to structure as a `dataclass`. However I was not sure how I can pass the `date_str` param without `__init__` in the `dataclass`. Any thoughts?

```
class FieldDateTime():
    def __init__(self, data, d_format='%m/%d/%y %I:%M %p'):
        try:
            self.data = datetime.strptime(data, d_format)
        except ValueError as e:
            raise ValueError('Dateformat incorrect')

    def __call__(self):
        return self.data

class NormalClass:
    def __init__(self, id, date_str):
        self.id: int = id
        self.dt: FieldDateTime = FieldDateTime(date_str)

@dataclass
class DataClassObj:
    id: int
    dt: FieldDateTime(date_str)
```

How do I pass the date_str as an argument in the data class representation (DataClassObj) without the init?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question has to be more detailed, but I think this is what you're looking for:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from datetime import datetime
from dataclasses import dataclass, InitVar, field


class FieldDateTime:
    def __init__(self, data, d_format='%m/%d/%y %I:%M %p'):
        try:
            self.data = datetime.strptime(data, d_format)
        except ValueError as e:
            raise ValueError('Dateformat incorrect')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({self.data})"

    def __call__(self):
        return self.data


@dataclass
class NormalDataClass:
    id: int
    date_str: InitVar[str]
    dt: FieldDateTime = field(init=False)

    def __post_init__(self, date_str):
        self.dt = FieldDateTime(date_str)


print(NormalDataClass(10, '09/04/21 08:11 PM'))
```

output (given the dataclass-like `__repr__` implementation on FieldDateTime to make it look a bit better):

```
NormalDataClass(id=10, dt=FieldDateTime(2021-09-04 20:11:00))
```

[from doc](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/#init-only-variables):

> Init-only fields are added as parameters to the generated `__init__`
> method, and are passed to the optional `__post_init__` method.

So we can use `InitVar` for our `date_str` and pass it to `__post_init__` to create our `FieldDateTime` object.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If i understood you correctly you want to use python dataclasses to achieve default initialization of the class instances fields. This feature is available [since Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) and it implicitly adds `__init__` constructor to the class which initializes the class instance with default values you specify.

The code using it would look like below:

```
from datetime import datetime


class FieldDateTime():
    def __init__(self, data, d_format='%m/%d/%y %I:%M %p'):
        try:
            self.data = datetime.strptime(data, d_format)
        except ValueError as e:
            raise ValueError('Dateformat incorrect')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)


from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class NormalDataClass:
    id: int = 0 # default id
    dt: FieldDateTime = FieldDateTime("02/03/20 05:20 AM") # default date
```

Below code

```
ndc = NormalDataClass()
print(ndc.id)
print(ndc.dt)
```

prints:

```
0
2020-02-03 05:20:00
```

Comment: User wants to be able to pass the variable date_str as an argument. Your solution hard-codes it to a string.